# Angular4x : ngx-cookie-service with expire parameter

Tags: angular, ngx-cookie-service

I am using  ngx-cookie-service component but as soon as i close the browser the cookies disappears, maybe i have to set the expire parameter but i can't get it , below what the the documentation says:

```
set( name: string, value: string, expires?: number | Date, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean ): void;
```

(I tried with number but it seems that doesn't work)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I've solved it like that

```
this.expiredDate = new Date();
this.expiredDate.setDate( this.expiredDate.getDate() + 7 );

//write
this.cookieService.set( 'key',JSON.stringify('value'), this.expiredDate);

//read
console.log(JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get( 'key'));
```

Remember to inject the cookieService

```
  import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}
```

Install

```
npm install angular2-cookie --save
```

Answer (score 8):

Use number, which is the 3rd parameter, where the number represents the number of days until it expires.

For example, if you want the cookie to expire in 365 days, use:

```
this.cookieService.set('cookieName', cookieValue, 365);
```

Hope that helps!