# How to set the cookie expire date with `ngx-cookie-service`

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-cookie-service

I am using `ngx-cookie-service` for my angular5 app. any one help me to show the way to set the expire date?

I try like this:

```
setCookies($event){
        this.cookieService.set( 'retailAppCookies', "true", 30 );
        this.cookieService.set( 'expires', '2030-07-19' );
    }
```

But not works. any one help me?

Comment: Does this post addresses the same issue? I think the answer there could help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817792/angular4x-ngx-cookie-service-with-expire-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2021, you can add Date but it has be date instance. The following example sets cookie with 1 hour expiration

```
cookieService.set('test', 'Hello World', { expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() +  1000 * 60 * 60); });
```

See the API [documentation](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service#set-name-string-value-string-expires-number--date-path-string-domain-string-secure-boolean-samesite-lax--strict--none--void) for more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can not add date in **ngx-cookie-service** you have to add number of days like

```
 this.cookieService.set('CookieName', 'Cookie Value', 5);
```

this will expire after 5 days