# How to set secure flag in my cookie using ngx-cookie-service for Angular?

Tags: angular, cookies, ngx-cookie-service

I want to set the secure flag in my cookie when I create it. I think I have the solution but I want to be sure in order to continue. I use the [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) to set my cookie.

Here is my code:

```
const now = new Date();
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 8);
const secureFlag = true;
this.cookieService.set('usertype', 'agent', now, '/', '/', secureFlag);
```

The thing is that I don't know if I have to declare the 4th and 5th parameter like that because if I don't declare them it shows error.

For example I try this:

```
const now = new Date();
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 8);
const secureFlag = true;
this.cookieService.set('usertype', 'agent', now, secureFlag);
```

and it warns me with `Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

Do I have to use `'/'` for `path` and `domain` parameters when I don't want to define them?

Comment: Funny thing to note. If, using ngx-cookie-service, you try to place a secure flag like so `this.cookieService.set('name', value, path, domain, secureFlag)`, chrome will not allow it.
Tryed it and chrome 80 refused the cookie. Haven't tryed it on another browser though.

Also, note, `domain`, if you're not sure of what to put there, juste use `undefined`.

Answer (score 7):

This will work, also to do testing disable `SameSite` by default cookies on Google Chrome if you are having problems with Google Chrome.

Paste this into your browser and it will take you to the SameSite settings and disable.

```
chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies

this.cookieService.set('sessionuser', username, 1 , '/', 'localhost', false, "Lax" );
```

Answer (score 4):

The get method of CookieService supports the following parameters:

```
    /**
     * @param name     Cookie name
     * @param value    Cookie value
     * @param expires  Number of days until the cookies expires or an actual `Date`
     * @param path     Cookie path
     * @param domain   Cookie domain
     * @param secure   Secure flag
     * @param sameSite OWASP samesite token `Lax`, `None`, or `Strict`. Defaults to `None`
     */
    set(name: string, value: string, expires?: number | Date, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean, sameSite?: 'Lax' | 'None' | 'Strict'): void;
```

The error `Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'` 
it’s because you’re sending the secure parameter instead of path.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in development & you don't have ssl, then `secureFlag: true`, might not work.

e.g .

```
this.cookieService.set('cookieName', 'somevalue', 1, '/','localhost', false, "Strict");
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this post addresses the same issue? I think the answer there could help you.
[Angular4x : ngx-cookie-service with expire parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817792/angular4x-ngx-cookie-service-with-expire-parameter)

Comment: Well in the link you provided they solve the problem with the expire parameter when setting the cookie. My question here is if I have to add the 4th and 5th parameter even if it is `null` (for example, this.cookieService.set('usertype', 'agent', now, null, null, secureFlag);). In addition you could comment that and not post it as an answer but thanks anyway.

Comment: One thing is the security flag and another the expiration of the cookie. The post has nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you alreadey solved in one of your comments, since is the solution I try and succeded, only add a last parameter (Lax), but is not necesary:

```
this.cookieService.set('usertype', 'agent', now, null, null, secureFlag, 'Lax');
```

I try to add '/' in the *path* and *domain* parameters, that only works in 'path', but setting both to null do the work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below one ("Lax"/"Strict"):-

const secureFlag = true;
this.cookieService.set('cookieName', 'somevalue', undefined, undefined,'undefined, secureFlag , "Strict");